# How to create item-item and user-user matrix for collaborative filtering in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I want to understand item-item and user-user matrixes for collaborative filtering and how it is different from Content-Based filtering.

Item-User:

```
 User1  User2 ... UserN
 Movie1  0        1   ...  0
 Movie2  1        1   ...  0 
  .
  .
  .
 MovisM  1        0   ...  0
```

Starting with a Movies-User matrix, how can I create simple item-item and user-user matrixes in Microsoft Excel using Visual Basic for Applications?

Item-Item:

```
     Movie1  Movie2 ... MovieN
 Movie1  0        1   ...  0
 Movie2  1        1   ...  0 
  .
  .
  .
 MovieM  1        0   ...  0
```

User-User:

```
     User1  User2 ... UserN
 User1  0        1   ...  0
 User2  1        1   ...  0 
  .
  .
  .
 UserM  1        0   ...  0
```

At the moment I am calculating the correlation coefficient between User1 and UserN with the Microsoft Excel function CORREL. I have the following Visual Basic for Applications code to calculate the Cosine Similarity. Which is very well explained here http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/

```
Function cosSim(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Variant
Dim wf As Object
Set wf = WorksheetFunction
On Error Resume Next
cosSim = wf.SumProduct(a, b) / Sqr(wf.SumSq(a)) / Sqr(wf.SumSq(b))
If Err <> 0 Then cosSim = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
=cosSim({1,2,3}, {4,-5,6})
=cosSim(A1:A3, B1:B3)
```

In this thread a simple example is given for an item-item matrix.
[Collaborative Filtering: Non-Personalized item-to-item similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390312/collaborative-filtering-non-personalized-item-to-item-similarity)

Comment: This is a very broad question. Why not ask about one matrix at a time? It would be better if in VBA you start implementing the algorithm discussed in the question that you link to and ask a question about your code. Where are you stuck? It might not be your intention, but your question reads as if you want detailed instructions on how to implement a nontrivial algorithm in VBA. That would require writing a custom tutorial. If your question is in fact more focused than "how do I do everything" -- please clarify.

Comment: I think that the matrixes go hand in hand and I want to learn the differences between the matrixes and when and why I should or shouldn't use them. I have the Visual Basic for Applications code to calculate the cosine similarity but I am not sure how to use the code with my data. Since I don't fully understand the code I am not sure what the cosine similarity tells me about the relationship between users and/or items.